# Зацикливание анимации XML

Tags: java, android, xml, анимация

Надо зациклить, чтобы объект уменьшался, а потом увеличивался и так бесконечное количество раз.

Сделал вот так:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="2000"
    android:fillAfter="false"
    android:repeatMode="reverse">
<scale
    android:fromXScale="0.7"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="0.7"
    android:toYScale="1.0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"/>
</set>
```

Но оно только увеличивается и все. Помогите, буду благодарен.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пожалуйста, добавьте в **scale** аттрибут **repeatCount** со значением **infinite**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:duration="2000"
 android:fillAfter="false"
 android:repeatMode="reverse">
<scale
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:fromXScale="0.7"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="0.7"
    android:toYScale="1.0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"/>
</set>
```